# How do you get user click coordinates with addEventListener then repeat that click with elementFromPoint().click()?

Tags: javascript, dom

How would I get the coordinates of a user's click then repeat that click right after or a second after?

When I use the code below the console.log of the second line is printed multiple times but the intended effect of the second click doesn't work. However, it works when I put numbers into elementFromPoint like in document.elementFromPoint(11, 54).click();

```js
    myPost.addEventListener("click", e => {
      console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);

      var xclick = e.clientX;
      var yclick = e.clientY;
      

      document.elementFromPoint(11, 54).click(); //This works

      document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY).click(); //These don't work
      document.elementFromPoint(xclick, yclick).click(); //These don't work


      //These don't work
      setTimeout(function() {
         // document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY).click();
         document.elementFromPoint(xclick, yclick).click();
       }, 1000);

    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div id="myPost">Click me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click me</div>
  

</body>
</html>
```

Edit: It seems the recorded mouse coordinates become "0 0" after the initial click. Why is that?

Comment: Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `[<>]` in the editor toolbar) to create a runnable example here on Stack Overflow so people don't have to go to another site.

Comment: When you do `.click()` -- it's coords are 0, 0. It's expected.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Really cool feature. I just added it. Thanks!

Comment: @Kosh Do I pass the coordinates into the click function like .click(e.clientX, e.clientY) ?

Comment: When you call `click()` the Event object passed in has its `clientX` and `clientY` properties set to 0. You need to construct your own `Event` object and use `dispatchEvent` to trigger the event. See [MDN's article about creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need to keep the coords:

```js
const myPost = document.querySelector('p');
let t;
myPost.addEventListener("click", e => {
  console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);

  const newClick = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
  newClick.initMouseEvent('click', !0, !0, window, 1, e.screenX, e.screenY, e.clientX, e.clientY, !1, !1, !1, !1, 0, null);
  
  clearTimeout(t);
  t = setTimeout(function() {
    document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY).dispatchEvent(newClick);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<p>click me</p>
```

Comment: `initMouseEvent` is deprecated in favor of constructors. See [MDN's article on `createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent)

Comment: @HereticMonkey, you're right, but I bet we want to be crossbrowser. I've already faced the problems with the constructor, so this should work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var xclick
 var yclick
 myPost.addEventListener("click", e => {


   if (xclick === undefined) {
     xclick = e.clientX;
     yclick = e.clientY;
   }


   console.log(xclick, yclick);
   //  document.elementFromPoint(11, 54).click(); //This works

   document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY).click(); //These don't work
   document.elementFromPoint(xclick, yclick).click(); //These don't work


   //These don't work
   setTimeout(function() {
     // document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY).click();
     document.elementFromPoint(xclick, yclick).click();
   }, 1000);

 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div id="myPost">Click me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click meClick me Click me Click me</div>
  

</body>
</html>
```

As far as I understand, with every click event, your variables were re-setting.
Keeping them outside the function and updating them only if they are not `undefined` would get you desired result